# Check Value in one table column to find info to its related TABLE

Tags: php, mysql

Says that I have only three table for this. Order_List, Delivery_Order, and InfiStall_Order:

`Order_List` is the table for the whole orders that we have received so far, included but not limited to: the code of the products(**'id_cart'**), the name of the customer(**'customer'**), the used payment (**'payment'**), and the method of getting the products(**'method'**).

---

```
 ------------------------------------------------------
 id_cart         customer        payment       method
 ------------------------------------------------------
  0001           Klaudia         creditcard   Infistall  
  0002           Klaudia         paypal       Delivery 
  0003           MyFather        Transfer     Delivery 
  0004           MyMother        Transfer     Infistall 
 -------------------------------------------------------
```

Method of getting the product is divided into two methods: 'Delivery' & 'InfiStall':

Delivery is where the customer want the products to delivered to an address, while InfiStall is where the customer want to get the product by picking it up to our listed stores.

Because Both of Delivery and InfiStall will have a specific additional information, such as location, city, or country, they have to have their own table. As follows:

Say that this is the table of delivery `Delivery_Order`

```
  ------------------------------------------------------
  id_cart         location        address       status
  ------------------------------------------------------
  0003           Asia            Japan        Delivered 
  0004           Africa          Maroko       Delivered 
 -------------------------------------------------------
```

And say that this is the table of Infistall `InfiStall_Order`

```
 ------------------------------------------------------
 id_cart         location        address       status
 ------------------------------------------------------
  0001           Pluto           Nowhere       Picked-up  
  0002           Markurius       Showhere      Waiting 
 -------------------------------------------------------
```

all table has column named id_cart. That's why, FIRST, I want to select all the information based on the id_card.

What I want is,

When the customer login to his account (say that the user named `Klaudia`) and she will see their orders history, they will see like this:

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 id_cart         products        quantity       invoices     status
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
                 this               2             $20        Picked
  0001           that               1             $20       (See Detail)
                 those              2             $20        
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
                 this               2             $20        Delivered
  0002           that               1             $20       (See Detail)
                 those              2             $20        
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And then, when `Klaudia` click the `See Detail` links, it will show the information from deliver_order/infistall_order

Comment: What do you want exactly? All columns from all tables?

Comment: @Tivi what I want is in the updated question.

Comment: How is it that you have some `id_cart`s across both `InfiStall_Order` and `Delivery_Order`?

Answer (score 2):

You have to select every item specifically because some columns will be ambigous (have the same name across the tables.

```
SELECT
  o.id_cart  AS id,
  d.location AS deliverLocation,
  i.location AS infiLocation,
  ... etc
FROM Order_List o
LEFT JOIN Delivery_Order d
  ON o.id_cart = d.id_cart
LEFT JOIN InfiStall_Order i
  ON o.id_cart = i.id_cart
WHERE o.customer = 'Klaudia'
```

In the case that either of the tables Delivery_Order or InfiStall_Order may not contain any rows, you must use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.

**Edit:** Now showing with LEFT JOIN

**Edit2:**

If the data is only expected to be in table Delivery_Order or InfiStall_Order, then use a CASE to evaluate it:

```
SELECT
  *,
  CASE
    WHEN d.id_cart IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS isInDeliver
FROM Order_List o
LEFT JOIN Delivery_Order d
  ON o.id_cart = d.id_cart
LEFT JOIN InfiStall_Order i
  ON o.id_cart = i.id_cart
WHERE o.customer = 'Klaudia'
```

Comment: Show me with left join instead.

Comment: When you check it if it is Delivery or InfiStall?

Comment: @klaudia Now I check if it is in deliver or not. See the last edit

Comment: what is `isInDeliver`? reffering to? because it shows error there!

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation `#1146 - Table 'igniter.Order_List' doesn't exist`

Comment: @klaudia isInDeliver is just a new name for the result coming from the CASE. It's pretty much the same as doing a regular `SELECT column AS newColumnName`. If more selection sets follow the CASE, be sure to add a comma after the `isInDeliver` Make sure your tables exist. Easy as that